# Exception when ReportDocument is Exported, Saved, or Printed

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reportdocument

This one might be a tough one to explain. I've got a program which fills in a pre-built Crystal Report (CR 2011) based on an Oracle Database. I've applied the logon information to all the tables in the report (and all the tables in the 5 sub reports) through MSDN tutorial based code.
If I do not add any code to do anything with the report once it's refreshed (such as saving it, or sending it to a printer) it will run through my code without issue. However, if I add any code that makes the program useful, it breaks with the below Exception.

Here is my relevant code:

```
    try
    {
        for (Intcount = 1; Intcount < rName.Count(); Intcount++)
        {
            LogFile.LogMessage(path, sReportPath);
            LogFile.LogMessage(path, sReportPath + rName.ElementAt(Intcount));

            //This line is loading "C:\...\Policy Reinstatement.rpt" which is valid
            cr.Load(sReportPath + rName.ElementAt(Intcount));

            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = sDataSource;
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "";
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = sUserID;
            crConnectionInfo.Password = sPassword;

            cr.SetDatabaseLogon(crConnectionInfo.UserID, crConnectionInfo.Password,
                crConnectionInfo.ServerName, crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName);

            //Method for looping through each table in the report
            //and applying the Connection Info to each of them
            SetDBLogonForReport(crConnectionInfo, cr);
            //Method for looping through all SubReports,
            //then calling the SetDBLogonForReport method.
            SetDBLogonForSubReports(crConnectionInfo, cr);

            CrystalReportViewer rpt = new CrystalReportViewer();
            rpt.ReportSource = cr;
            try
            {
                rpt.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //It does not throw on this exception
                LogFile.LogError(path, ex);
                throw;
            }
            cr.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 1);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         //It throws on this exception
         LogFile.LogError(path, ex);
         throw;
     }
```

Here is the exception:

```
Message: Failed to open the connection.Policy Reinstatement {35A94093-A135-462DA5AA-F5FDD3E2D62B}.rpt 
Source: CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion
StackTrace:    at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.HandleException(Exception exception)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.GetLastPageNumber(ReportPageRequestContext reqContext)
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.PrintToPrinter(Int32 nCopies, Boolean collated, Int32 startPageN, Int32 endPageN)
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(Int32 nCopies, Boolean collated, Int32 startPageN, Int32 endPageN)
Inner Message: 
Failed to open the connection.
Policy Reinstatement {35A94093-A135-462D-A5AA-F5FDD3E2D62B}.rpt 
Inner Source: rptcontrollers.dll 
Inner StackTrace:    at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.GetLastPageNumber(RequestContext pRequestContext)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.GetLastPageNumber(ReportPageRequestContext reqContext)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is confusing you about this?  It seems pretty clear that your db connection information is not working.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs If it wasn't working, why would it not throw an exception earlier in the code, with my Try..Catch block around the refresh command?

Comment: Why would it?  If it fails at the `cr.SetDatabaseLogon`, that's not in scope for your inner `try...catch` block.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified, I can step through the code and it makes it all the way to the "cr.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 1);" line without issue.

Comment: The exception is pretty clear; the problem seems to be with your data connection.  I would focus my attention on that.  It's possible that the connection to the database is not made until `PrintToPrinter` is called, your `Refresh` call notwithstanding.